# Python Declaring a function with an index

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, parameters

I want to write a function that takes three parameters - `type1`, `type2`, and `index` - and should return `type1` with the elements of `type2` inserted at the index.

Here is some sample I/O

```
do_something ([21, 32, 23], ['f', 'g', 'c'], 2)

[21, 32, 'f', 'g', 'c', 23]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def do_something(type1, type2, index)

return do_something
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong here, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but what you've got so far is nothing... you've just written out a spec. How do you think you should do this?

Comment: How to insert the elements of one list in between the ith and i+1th index of a second list @tobias_k.

Comment: how to call the parameter index?

Comment: The 3rd argument (2) is bound to the parameter  (index) when the function is invoked in the example. After fixing the syntax issues (lack of colon and indent) it will parse just fine. Now you have to *do* something the the parameters (and values they name).

Comment: If [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388812/python-declaring-a-function-with-a-index) gets closed, don't just create a new anonymous account so you can post it again.

Comment: In what sense is the list `[21, 32, 23]` a "type"?

Answer (score 3):

I think this answers your question and does what you want:

```
def do_something(list1, list2, index):
    list1[index:index] = list2
    return list1

print(do_something([21, 32, 23], ['f', 'g', 'c'], 2))
```

Output:

```
[21, 32, 'f', 'g', 'c', 23]
```

Comment: whats the difference of this one from the last one?

Comment: It doesn't call the `insert()` method which nested `list2` inside of `list1` -- instead it effectively inserts the individual elements of `list2` into `list1` at the specified index.

Comment: Minor correction: It does not really insert the elements into `list1`, but creates a new list without modifying either of the lists. ;-)

Comment: @tobias_k: Picky, picky... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you're not sure how to access a list by index, you use the index access operator, i.e. `[]`

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
>>> x[1] = 99
>>> x
[1, 99, 3]
>>> x[2] = [1,2,3]
>>> x
[1, 99, [1, 2, 3]]
```

The interactive interpreter is your friend! `dir(list)` and the `help()` function are also friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Index isn't a special sort of parameter.  You'll pass it in just like anything else.  What you have is fine, but you'll have to figure out how to write the function in between your def and return statements.  Take a look at the docs and come back if you have specific questions on them, and can show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter is an index to the list, then "index" is perfectly fine as a parameter name. There are some names in python which you should avoid, such as "list" or "str", but "index" is not one of them. If you think the meaning of the parameter is unclear, you can always add a comment or a docstring to the function.

---

As for the function body, you can insert another list into a list using this notation:

```
def do_something(type1, type2, index):
    type1[index:index] = type2
```

What this does is: It takes the elements of the list `type1` from `index` (inclusive) to `index` (exclusive) and *replaces* them with the given list. Since the slice is empty, no elements are actually replaced, but the second list is *inserted* at that position.

Note that this will *modify* the original list `type1`. Use this to create and return a new list instead:

```
def do_something(type1, type2, index):
    return type1[:index] + type2 + type1[index:]
```

This takes the elements of `type1` up to `index` (excluding) and concatenates them with `type2` and the elements of `type1` from `index` onwards (including).

In both cases, the result is

```
[21, 32, 'f', 'g', 'c', 23]
```